# Probability for brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How can I prove it?

> For $b>a>0$, show that 
>   $$
> \operatorname{Pr}\left({\sup_{t\geqslant 0}\left(\frac{b+X(t)}{1+t}\right)\geqslant a}\right)=e^{-2a(a-b)}
> $$
>   where $X(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/133971/822) and let $t \to \infty$.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge  I don`t know how to do with $\frac{b+X(t)}{1+t}$. It is not a Brownian motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inequality $\sup_{t\geqslant 0}\left(\frac{b+X(t)}{1+t}\right)\geqslant a$ implies that there exists a time, for which $X(t) > a t + (a-b)$, i.e. the hitting time $T_{a,a-b}$ (when the Brownian motion crosses line $a t + (a-b)$) is finite:
$$
   \operatorname{Pr}\left({\sup_{t\geqslant 0}\left(\frac{b+X(t)}{1+t}\right)\geqslant a}\right) = \operatorname{Pr}\left( T_{a,a-b} < \infty \right) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \operatorname{Pr}\left( T_{a,a-b} < t \right) 
$$ 
Now use the result from the [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133971/822) as suggested by Nate.