# Path properties of Brownian Motion: relation between its maximum and hitting time

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian motion.
$$T_a=\inf\{t>0,B(t)=a\}$$
$$M(t)=\max_{0\le s\le t} B(s)$$

There is a statement in Durrett's textbook (3rd last line in page 318, 4th edition):
$$\{T_a<t\}=\{M(t)>a\}$$
I don't quite understand why this holds. Inclusion $\supseteq$ is easy to get.

But why is $\subseteq$ true? It excludes the event "$M(t)=a$", is there something wrong?

Comment: The identity holds only up to the null set $\{M(t)=a\}$.

Comment: @Did oh,I see, the author does take the $\mathbb P$ then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sets $\{T_a<t\}$  and $\{M(t)>a\}$  are equal to up to a null set, because the event $M(t)=a$ has probability zero. Indeed, both $T_a$ and $M(t)$ are continuously distributed random variables: [Distribution of hitting time of line by Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133628/).