# Hitting time of Brownian motion of a straight line

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion starting in zero,  $a, b \in \Bbb R$.
Let $T_{a, b}$ denote the first hitting time of the straight line $s\mapsto a +bs$, i.e
$$
T_{a, b} = \inf \Bigl\{t \geq 0: W_t = a +bt \Bigr\}.
$$

My question: is it true that
$$
T_{a, b} \stackrel{d}{=} T_{-a, -b}?
$$
From an intuitive point this seems to be true, however I am blanking on giving a formal proof.

My goal is to calculate $\Bbb P(T_{a,b} \leq t) $ for $a < 0$, similar to 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133628/distribution-of-hitting-time-of-line-by-brownian-motion) .

Comment: Yes, since $W \overset{d}{=} -W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$T_{a,b}=\inf\{t \geq 0; W_t = a+bt\} \stackrel{d}{=} \inf\{t \geq 0; B_t = a+bt\}$$

for any two Brownian motions $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$. How to choose $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ such that the right-hand side equals $T_{-a,-b}$?