# integral of exponential (Green) function with trigonometric variable

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am searching for a tip on how to handle the following integral,
$\int_c^\infty e^{-x^2}\sin\dfrac{b}{x^2}~dx$
and also
$\int_c^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos\dfrac{b}{x^2}~dx$
where both $c$ and $b$ are real. I could not find it in the Integrals table. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: It can expressed by the Error function

Comment: The erfc function would in fact be the integral of the first factor, but the cosine or the sine would change that. I did not find an expression for it. Did you?

Comment: You may be interested in the first answer in this question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128687/bessel-function-integral-and-mellin-transform