# Distributions of a product and of sums of products of iid, standard normal random variables.

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, mellin-transform, polygamma

It is known how to compute the distribution of a product of independent random variables.
The results boils down to evaluating the inverse Mellin transform of a product of Mellin transforms of the original probability densities.This approach is mentioned in the so called [Slater theorem in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128687/bessel-function-integral-and-mellin-transform?rq=1) and the whole theory is set out in this paper

*Springer, M. D.; Thompson, W. E.*, [**The distribution of products of independent random variables**](https://doi.org/10.1137/0114046), SIAM J. Appl. Math. 14, 511-526 (1966). [ZBL0144.40701](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0144.40701).

.

We used this approach to compute the result for iid, normal variables with mean zero and variance one. In other words $x= t_1 t_1 \cdots t_n$ where $t_i \sim N(0,1) $ for $i=1,\cdots,n$. Define ${\tilde x}_n:= x 2^{-n/2}$
and

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak A}_m^{(n)}(x) &:=& \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \left. \frac{d^{n-1}}{d \epsilon^{n-1}} 
[\Gamma\left(-m+\epsilon\right) \epsilon ]^n \cdot x^{-2 \epsilon} \right|_{\epsilon=0} \\
&=& \left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{(+1)^m}{[m!]^2} \left( \left\{ n \psi^{(0)}(1+m) \right\} + (-2 \log(x)) \right) & \mbox{if $n=2$}\\
\frac{(-1)^m}{[m!]^3} \left( 
\left\{\frac{n^2}{2!} [ \psi^{(0)}(1+m) ]^2 - \frac{n}{2!} [ \psi^{(1)}(1+m) ]^{1} + \frac{n}{3!} \pi^2\right\} + 
3 \psi^{(0)}(1+m) \cdot (-2 \log(x)) +
\frac{1}{2} \cdot (-2 \log(x))^2
\right)& \mbox{if $n=3$} \\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
where $\psi^{j}(\cdot)$ is the polygamma function.

For fixed $n=2,3,4,\cdots$ and arbitrary $m,x$ the quantities above can be generated using the following formula:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\mathfrak A}_m^{(n)}(x) = 
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}
\frac{(-1)^{m n}}{[m!]^n} \cdot
\sum\limits_{0 \le p_1 \le p_2 \le n-1}
\frac{\pi^{p_1}}{p_1! (p_2-p_1)! (n-1-p_2)!}
\left(\left.\frac{d^{p_1}}{d \epsilon^{p_1}} \left( \frac{\sin(\epsilon)}{\epsilon} \right)^{-n} \right|_{\epsilon:> \pi \epsilon} \right)
\cdot
\left(\frac{d^{p_2-p_1}}{d \epsilon^{p_2-p_1}} \exp\left[-n \log(\frac{\Gamma(1+m-\epsilon)}{\Gamma(1+m)}) \right]
\right)
\cdot 
(-2 \log(x))^{n-1-p_2}
\end{eqnarray}

Then the result reads:

\begin{equation}
\rho_X(x) = \frac{2^{-\frac{n}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}} \cdot \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \left( {\tilde x}_n \right)^{2 m} \cdot {\mathfrak A}_m^{(n)}({\tilde x}_n ) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now , by using the Mathematica code snippet below, we have plotted the result for $n=2,3$ (in Blue and Purple respectively). Here we go:

```
(*Distribution of a product of iid, standard Gaussian random \
variables.*)
n =.;
M = 20;
xs = Array[# &, 100, {0.001, 10}];
gamma = 0.1; Vals = {};
Do[
  Which[n == 2,
   vals1 = 
     2^(-n/2)/Pi^(n/2) Total[
         Table[(# 2^(-n/2))^(2 m) ((-1)^(m n)/(m!)^2 (n) PolyGamma[0, 
               1 + m] + 1/(m!)^2 (-2 Log[# 2^(-n/2)])), {m, 0, 
           M}]] & /@ xs;,
   n == 3,
   vals1 = 2^(-n/2)/Pi^(n/2) Total[Table[(# 2^(-n/2))^(2 m) (
            (-1)^(m n)/(m!)^3 (1/2! n^2 PolyGamma[0, 1 + m]^2 + 
                1/2! (-n)  PolyGamma[1, 1 + m] + n Pi^2/3!) +
             (3 (-1)^m PolyGamma[0, 1 + m])/
              Gamma[1 + m]^3 (-2 Log[# 2^(-n/2)]) +
             1/2 (-1)^m/(m!)^3 (-2 Log[# 2^(-n/2)])^2
            ), {m, 0, M}]] & /@ xs;
   ];
  
  vals2 = 
   2^(-1 - n/2)/
       Pi^(n/2) 1/(2 Pi ) NIntegrate[(# 2^(-n/2))^(-(gamma + 
             I xi)) Gamma[(gamma + I xi)/2]^n, {xi, -Infinity, 
        Infinity}] & /@ xs;
  Print[{n, Mean@Abs[vals1/vals2 - 1]}];
  Vals = Join[Vals, {vals1}];
  , {n, 2, 3}];

ListLogPlot[Transpose[{xs, #}] & /@ Vals, PlotRange :> All, 
 PlotStyle :> {Blue, Purple}]
```

[image]

As we can see the distribution is leptokurtic with the fatness of the tail increasing with $n$. This is interesting because the Gaussian distribution does not have fat tails.

---

Having said all this my question would be can we generalize this approach to computing distributions of linear combinations of products of iid , standard random variables? In other words I would like to be able to compute the probability density of a a following variable $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} {\mathfrak A}_{n,k} x_n x_{n-1-k} $ where $x_k \sim N(0,1) $ for $k=0,\cdots, n$ and $\left\{ {\mathfrak A}_{n,k} \right\}_{k=0}^{n-1}$ are some deterministic coefficients. How would we go about doing it?